# How to change Directory path to be dynamic with selecting file

Tags: php, path, upload, directory

So I want to make the path dynamically from this code, I want to change that directory path with select file, and save to same filename from that pdf to xml

This is opening the file

```
$cfile = curl_file_create('D:\\test3.pdf', 'application/pdf');
```

This is output file

```
file_put_contents ("D:\\test3.xml", $result);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve here - what path are you trying to dynamically change?

Comment: sorry for my bad english , i'm trying to change that ("D:\\test3.pdf') with automatic selected file path on my pc not write in code.

Comment: Can you perhaps show what your desired outcome should be in this scenario?

Comment: you can scan a directory and list all its files and sub-directories using `scandir`. The documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: in this case i just need only get the path of file to be uploaded on my code.

Comment: for example my manual code is 
$cfile = curl_file_create('D:\\test3.pdf', 'application/pdf');

but i want make it automatically filled making it to be variable 
like 
$cfile = curl_file_create($_FILES['filename'], 'application/pdf');

Comment: Try [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get info about the path.  as in `$dir = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)`

Comment: I have to select a file first then the path will change as my selection path

Comment: How you reach at 'D:\\test3.pdf' ?
If you get it from a database, it is a good practice to save the location as "saved_to" and "saved_as" so you can reuse the "saved_to" information.